# There have any idea for this

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have one task from my lecture which is Java. Lecturer ask us to draw a custom chess game which is something similar with the below picture. I was thinking from past few days but are not able to get at all.

[image: Java shape will be something like this]

Instruction :

Sorry, if I am asking question wrongly. I am expecting some ideas and any references for in able to do this.

Comment: What part are you stuck on? You're going to have a hard time getting someone to give you the answer without showing what you've attempted and stuck on.

Comment: Nice chessboard. A little bit challenging to draw. It has to be done using custom painting or you can use Swing components like JLabel to be a cell in the board?

Comment: I have been try to start, but not success at all, i try which is useless to put here,

Comment: If you don't know how to start you probably should talk to your instructor. He's being paid to instruct you afterall.

Comment: I meet with him but he give some instruction but did not understand at all, We had around 230 student , but the bad story is no body are able to do it

Comment: There have any one who really can help us ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can write a code for you , but instead step to start will help you more to learn.
There can be many ways to write this one of is this.

### Steps to start

1. Create a JFrame.
2. Set layout to border layout
3. Create a JPanel -> set panel at the center of jframe
4. Set panel layout to grid layout of  11 x 11
5. Create jable objects in for loop and add in Jpanel components.
6. Control background color of jlabel to form a structure shown in image.
7. For pawn, knight,you can use jlabel images
8. Build you logic to move or change jlabel to acive your requirement

Update and correction are invited

Comment: Appreciate, after i done i will post my updated code

Comment: You said -> Create jable objects in for loop and add in Jpanel components. ., what do u mean by jable ,(may be u mean jtable) , how i should write for loop

Comment: And also, I am unable to generate jtable if i follow your step :(

Comment: Its typo error jlabel not jtable.create jlabel and add components in jpanel which has layout set as gridlayout

Comment: Easy to say, I am trying from yesterday, not able to do it yet :(

Comment: I done with draw the interface which is similar with the image :) , what i should do next